# Foreign language characters replaced by "?"

Tags: c, windows, command-line, command

I am working on a program which takes file/folder names as input. Currently when I try to run a file which has got foreign language character in its name it is replaced by a ? For each of its character. I am running my exe on command prompt so trying to run the particular file results in an error. When I am using DIR on command prompt it displays ? For each character of the file name. Is there any way to display the actual foreign language characters in command prompt as I believe that could be causing my exe not to work any of those files.
This is the text that I am trying to read - 科普書籍推展教案 which is being replaced by ? on the console.

Comment: What programming language is this program in?

Comment: The programming language I am using is C.

Comment: It´s hard to tell your actual question... a) Theoretically it´s possible to diplay all unicode chars in the console, but in realtity...forget it. b) To get file names with out ?, don´t use the externl program dir (which simply can´t do it properly), but ue FindFirstFileW etc. in your program.

Comment: @deviantfan my question is how would I be able to run a file with characters being replaced by ? and I am trying to run my exe in the console. The parameter that my exe takes is the file name.

Comment: Make sure the programs use Unicode (UTF-8) to communicate. That will be hard to impossible on windows though.

Comment: Have you tried using the names provided by `DIR /X`?

Comment: @pmg yes I did but it still prints ? for each foreign language character in the file name

Comment: The `WriteConsoleW` function should be able to write simple UTF-16 correctly; it can't cope with composite characters, though.  It *might* be sufficient for your needs.  For full support, you'll have to drop the console and write a GUI program.

Answer (score 0):

The command prompt can only display characters in your current ACP. So, if you have files with names outside the ACP, you're going to see ?. You can use changecp to pick a different CP, but here is no code page for full Unicode in the DOS box.

Inside your code, you need to learn to use 'W' API to work with full unicode pathnames. The safest thing is to just #define _UNICODE and use it uniformly.

Comment: Could you please give an example as I am a beginner and it will greatly help me in understanding.

Comment: Google for 'tchar' or Windows API Unicode and many examples will deliver themselves.

Comment: With `std::wstring` etc., there is no reason to use `TCHAR` in own code other than converting some pointers

Comment: @deviantfan Will I be able to use std::wstring in a C program??

Comment: No, sorry, that´s C++. but at least `wchar_t` and `char16_t` and ... are there in C too. `TCHAR´ is a relict from times where Windows versions with and without Unicode support were used both, to write programs which could be compiled for either one. Windows without Unicode at all is long dead, so... . Concerning the console problem: If you really need the console *and* need your program to be compatible with others (without source of them), you´re probably out of luck. If you have total control over everything, you could use UTF8, but its not easy to type manually on the keyboard :) Else: GUI